# lftp unable to connect to ftp site, but using filezilla can connect successfully

Tags: linux, ftp, connection, sftp, lftp

I can successfully connect to ftp server using filezilla with SFTP protocol.

But when I try to connect using lftp, and send `ls` command for listing remote folder, it just keeps on showing status connecting...

Here is my lftp command:

```
$ lftp -p 22222 -u dev001 sftp://111.222.333.444
Password: 
lftp dev001@111.222.333.444:~> debug
lftp dev001@111.222.333.444:~> ls
---- Running connect program (ssh -a -x -s -l dev001 -p 22222 111.222.333.444 sftp)
---> sending a packet, length=5, type=1(INIT), id=0
The authenticity of host '[111.222.333.444]:22222 ([111.222.333.444]:22222)' can't be established.
<--- RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxx/yyyyyy/zzzzzzzzz.
`ls' at 0 [Connecting...]
```

Please enlighten me

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A few minutes after posting the question, looks like I can solved it :D

I try to connect using sftp command line, and it ask to save the fingerprint, then successfully connected and work flawlessly.

```
$ sftp -P 22222 dev001@111.222.333.444
```

Then I retry lftp... and... it works :D

```
$ lftp -p 22222 -u dev001 sftp://111.222.333.444
Password: 
lftp dev001@111.222.333.444:~> debug
lftp dev001@111.222.333.444:~> ls
---- Running connect program (ssh -a -x -s -l dev001 -p 22222 111.222.333.444 sftp)
---> sending a packet, length=5, type=1(INIT), id=0
`ls' at 0 [Connecting...]
dev001@111.222.333.444's password: XXXX
<--- got a packet, length=95, type=2(VERSION), id=0
---- protocol version set to 3
---> sending a packet, length=10, type=16(REALPATH), id=1
<--- got a packet, length=57, type=104(NAME), id=1
---- home set to /sftp/dev001/app
---- path on wire is `/sftp/dev001/app'
---> sending a packet, length=27, type=11(OPENDIR), id=2
<--- got a packet, length=13, type=102(HANDLE), id=2
---- got file handle 00000000 (4)
---> sending a packet, length=13, type=12(READDIR), id=3
<--- got a packet, length=6395, type=104(NAME), id=3
---- file name count=53
---> sending a packet, length=13, type=12(READDIR), id=4
---> sending a packet, length=13, type=12(READDIR), id=5
<--- got a packet, length=28, type=101(STATUS), id=4
---- status code=1(EOF), message=End of file
---- eof
drwxr-xr-x   17 dev001    sftpusers     4096 Aug 29 16:03 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root         4096 Dec 23  2015 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 dev001    sftpusers       96 May 11  2016 .arcconfig
-rw-------    1 dev001    sftpusers    11022 Jul  4  2022 .bash_history
<deleted>
---> sending a packet, length=13, type=4(CLOSE), id=6
<--- got a packet, length=28, type=101(STATUS), id=5
---- status code=1(EOF), message=End of file
<--- got a packet, length=24, type=101(STATUS), id=6
---- status code=0(OK), message=Success
```

The problem is lftp not asking a question to save the fingerprint to known_host. I'm not sure why, maybe there's an option to activate it.

Thank you, hope that help others.

Cheers